# Gathering the average values of Get-Counter outputs

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to gather the average performance values of processes over a long period of time. Unfortunately, my script is only able to average all the gathered values, rather than the averages of the individual processes.

The script below is what I ended up with, which unfortunately doesn't give an output for each respective process:

```
Write-Output (Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time","\Process(Chrome)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 25 |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty CounterSamples |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty CookedValue |
    Measure-Object -Average).Average
```

Ideally, I'd like to have an object with the output values formatted like so:

```
Output.chrome = 5.1283123
Output.total = 23.128732
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time","\Process(Chrome)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 25 `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty CounterSamples `
| Group-Object -Property InstanceName `
| ForEach-Object { 
        $_ | Select-Object -Property Name, @{n='Average';e={($_.Group.CookedValue | Measure-Object -Average).Average}};
    } `
| Format-Table -AutoSize;
```

Output:

```
Name            Average
----            -------
_total 11.8878325281858
chrome 4.80058851283048
```

It'd be easy enough to conditionally rename the names.

EDIT: Try this for PowerShell v2.0:

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time","\Process(Chrome)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 25 `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty CounterSamples `
| Group-Object -Property InstanceName `
| ForEach-Object { 
        $_ | Select-Object -Property Name, @{n='Average';e={(($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property CookedValue -Average).Average)}};
    } `
| Format-Table -AutoSize;
```

Comment: When running the snippet you provided, the output appeared void of values: `Name, _total, chrome; Average, , `

Comment: @matchai Works for me as written on v4.0.

Comment: I'm running v2.0 on my end, so that could be why :(

Comment: In an attempt to narrow it down, I'm getting nothing for `$_ | Select-Object -Property Name, @{n='Average';e={$_.Group.CookedValue}};`. It's as though there's no CookedValue value being used in the objects.

Comment: Yep! Looks like that does the job on 2.0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach:

```
$chrome = @()
$total = @()
$counterName = "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time","\Process(Chrome)\% Processor Time"

Get-Counter -Counter $counterName -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 10 |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples | % {
        $object = New-Object psobject -Property @{
            InstanceName = $_.InstanceName
            CookedValue = $_.CookedValue
        }

        if($object.InstanceName -eq "Chrome") {
            $chrome += $object
        } else {
            $total += $object
        }
    }

$output = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Chrome = ($chrome | Measure-Object -Average CookedValue).Average
    Total = ($total| Measure-Object -Average CookedValue).Average
}

$output
```

Output:

```
          Chrome            Total
          ------            -----
5,61702990401208 31,4667298163454
```

Comment: When running that snippet above, I'm encountering the following error:

`Measure-Object : Property "CookedValue" cannot be found in any object(s) input.`

Comment: I have changed the syntax for the custom object, maybe this will work better with PS 2.0 ?